# Order confirmation status go out on "pending" status

Tags: order-email, magento2.4.5

I'm not a Magento expert, and do not have access to the underlying code, but work with a Magento website.

Since the latest update to Magento 2.4.5 we have noticed that when and order is made it is made with the "Pending(new)" status. This then triggers it to send out an order confirmation email even before payment is confirmed (through Stripe). If the order is declined the customer still gets the email and the order will remain in "pending" status. If the customer enters a new card Magento will then move the original order to "canceled" and make a whole new order with a status "pending" and send out another order confirmation email.

I see no where in the system->configuration->sales email to set when emails send out on any given status. Is there someway I can move it so that order confirmation emails are only sent at a later status?

Also, the behavior of creating an entire new order when a credit card is declined seems odd, is this expected behavior?

Thanks for any insight!

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the latest update to Magento 2.4.5 may have changed the default behavior for order status and email notifications. You may want to check with the Magento support team or your development team to see if there is a way to configure the system to only send out order confirmation emails after payment has been confirmed through Stripe.

Regarding the behavior of creating a new order when a credit card is declined, this is not the expected behavior. It may be a bug or issue with the Stripe payment module or Magento system itself.